# MongoDB query to C# equivalent ObjectID subset

Tags: c#, mongodb

So I have done as much research as sanely possible and could not come to a conclusion that worked for me.  I have a query I use in Mongo to only grab _id's that end with a certain character.  These are standard base 16 object ids in MongoDB.  What I want from this is to divide up work where the one doing the query is only working on Ids that end in the base 16 value.  So I would have 16 processes responsible for running their respective instructions against ObjectId where _id ends with 0-e.

```
db.Collection.find({ $where : "this._id.toString().match(/(SomeNumber)..$/i)"})
```

My question is what would be the C# driver equivalent of this I could use with other filters such as Builders.Filter.Lte("Somefield", someVal) and then .FindOne()?

My final would look something like

```
var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(Id matches regex);
var filter2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lte("Somefield", someVal);

var qfilter = filter1 & filter2;
var returndoc = Collection.FindOne(qfilter);
```

In hopes that this will return one document at a time where the last value of my object id matches the one I am interested in and also has Somefield less than someVal.

This is what I have tried thus far.

```
//This one doesn't work because objectId does not support regex comparison
var iDFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("_id", _threadIndexB16);

//These two never returned any values
var iDFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where("this._id.toString().match(/\"" + _myWantedIndex + "..$/i)\")";
var iDFilter = new BsonDocument("$where", "this._id.toString().match(/" + _myWantedIndex + "..$/i)");
```

Help converting this would be appreciated.  Alternatives are also welcome as long as the result is the document I am after.

Comment: I played around with this and also got stuck. My approach was to have an INT version of the hex ObjectId and then do a modulus on it. That didn't work because the Int property wasn't persisted. I did something like: public int IdNumeric => int.Parse(ObjectIdProperty.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber). I then thought about creating a new property in the document and setting the value to reflect the int version of the hex ObjectId but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I did read somewhere that was a solution to write the value into a new column and use that instead.  For me, sadly, it is for a database and code that has been running for quite some time.  I can't get buy in for a bigger change like that.  I appreciate the comment though.  I had an idea that I haven't been able to try yet either to just create the raw instruction through RunCommand.  I'm not sure if it returns the resulting document yet though.